# Acknowledge Funding for Contributions in Kind

Tags: funding

I have won an academic research grant by a major "Cloud" computing platform to run a large agent-based simulation. The grant is not paid in cash. Instead I receive credits to spend on the computing platform.

How do I acknowledge this? The usual *X is partially supported by...* line doesn't feel applicable for this type of award as it does not directly benefit me personally.

Comment: Usually, grant providers will indicate how they would like to be acknowledged.

Comment: Research grants often do not go to the researcher personally. They go to the university account earmarked for this research project. It benefits me, in the sense that I can do the research I want to do. But that is no different to the benefit you got from your grant. So, can you clarify what the personal benefits are that you expect from other types of grants?

Comment: Thank you @mmeent, I will reach out to them. Thanks Maarten, I am self-funded so I don't really know how grants work. What I wanted to say was that cash grants given to an institution might "trickle down" to individual researchers in the form of salaries. Benefits in-kind, however, cannot be used in this way but can only ever cover "direct" research costs.

Comment: How do these "credits" compare to say an allocation of compute time at a high-performance computing center? Can the credits only be redeemed for compute time, or are there other possibilities?

Comment: Technically the credits can be used for any service offered by the platform operator, @Anyon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We gratefully acknowledge X for in-kind contributions.

X is the legal name of the corporation.

Also mention any conflicts of interest related to the corporation.